# Assigning class variables via named parameters in constructor call in C++

Tags: c++

I am coming from C# background. There I could do something like this:

```
Callback callback = new Callback
    {
        src = src,
        callbackPtr = callbackPtr
    };
```

assuming there is only an empty constructor:

```
Callback(){}
```

and both variables are public.

Is there something like that in C++ or do I have to create parameterized constructor here?

Comment: Could you explain what it *means* in C#, for those of us who don't know it?

Comment: BTW That's a fairly new feature in C#, before you had to write `Callback callback = new Callback(); callback.src = src; callback.callbackPtr = callbackPtr;` ... and that idea works in C++ as well.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's a default constructor with an intializer for the named members `src` and `callbackPtr`.  This would be really dangerous in C++.

Answer (score 4):

If `Callback` is a plain-old-data (POD) type, you can do this:

```
Callback callback = {src, callbackPtr};
```

which uses the structure initialization syntax. It assumes that `src` and `callbackPtr` are listed in that order in the class definition.

This works in both C++03 and C++11. In C++11, non-POD classes can use this syntax by defining a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: In C++11, it can also work for a class with a two-parameter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
Callback* callback = new Callback
    {
        src,
        callbackPtr
    };
```

Assuming `Callback` has fields with the same data types in that order and - big caveat - the fields have to be public.

Comment: I am receiving "No matching constructor for initialization" compile error. Even though I defined empty ctor: Callback() {}

Comment: This calls a two-argument constructor using the uniform constructor syntax. It is not the same as the C# construct.

Comment: but then what's the benefit using that over new Callback(src, callbackPtr); ? I was trying to avoid using parameterized ctor.

Comment: There is no benefit aside from uniform notation, unless you are dealing with template code.

Comment: My first thought is: You are assigning a pointer of type `Callback *` to a variable of type `Callback`? I guess it is a typo, but then again I don't know every last rule of c++11.

Comment: Sorry, apparantly this one is only available for `structs` not `classes`. Which I wasn't aware of, since previously they were treated the same.

Comment: @nneonneo: Yes, it does compile if Callback is a struct.

Comment: This will work if `Callback` is an aggregate.  `class` vs `struct` doesn't matter.  Having public member variables and no constructor does matter.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I actually had this in my answer and then forgot to add it to my test and was confused at first.